# Simple geometry problem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, pythagorean-triples

So I'm asking this question because I'm afraid I would be doing a stupid mistake... the problem associated with this trigonometry problem isn't pulling off. Could you tell me whether my calculation is correct?

In this figure:

[image]

$r,x_0,y_0$ are known. From that I have to calculate $\Delta r$.

My formula came out to be

$$\Delta r = y_0 + \sqrt{2r^{2}\left(1-\cos\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{x_{0}}{r}\right)\right)\right)-x_{0}^{2}}$$

Note: $y_0$ is the vertical dotted distance.

Comment: The answers below are better geometric interpretations, but if you want to do it using trigonometry, then the above looks correct to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a$ be the radius of the smaller circle. Then, by the pythagorean theorem:
$$(a+y_0)^2+x_0^2 = r^2,$$
so: 
$$ a = -y_0+\sqrt{r^2-x_0^2}$$
and:
$$\Delta r = r-a = r+y_0-\sqrt{r^2-x_0^2}.$$

Comment: $y_0$ is the vertical dotted distance...

Comment: Understood. Hence the length of the hypotenuse of the right triangle having $x_0$ and $a+y_0$ as sides is $r$. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$$\Delta r - y_0 +\sqrt{r^2-x_{0}^{2}}=r$$

Thus

$$\Delta r = r+ y_0 -\sqrt{r^2-x_{0}^{2}}$$